# mongodb: collection.update inside cursor.each resolves before update is completed

Tags: mongodb, promise

First of all, I'm using [mongodb-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-promise) as a wrapper to MongoClient.

I need to fetch all records from a collection "people" that matches specific criteria and then update each of them.

For that I have this code to find all people:

```
return db.collection('people')

.then( (collection) => {
    // Store reference to collection for future use
    peopleCollection = collection;

    return collection.find({a:1})
})
```

An then invoke this to update each record:

```
.then( (people) => {

    // Process each people
    return people.each( (person) => {

        person.b = 2;

        // Where peopleCollection is a reference to my collection
        return peopleCollection.update({_id: person._id}, person)
    })
})
```

I then add another promise chain to fetch all people where b != 2 and I find many records and I counted them. But when I execute this script repeatedly, the count decreases which means mongo is still updating other records when the promise has already resolved. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
.then( (people) => {

// Process each people
return people.each( (person) => {


    // Where peopleCollection is a reference to my collection
    return peopleCollection.update({_id: person._id}, {$set:{b:2}})
  })
})
```

Comment: This made the query faster but still It does not solve the problem. The promise still resolves even the update was not finished yet.